# Call function from UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

I have a stupid problem with an UIActionSheet.
I want my function "sendMail" to be launched by clicking on the first button of my action sheet.

So here is what I did :

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%d", buttonIndex); 
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        sendMail(); 
    }
}
```

I declared my function sendMail in my .h file, it contains :

```
-(void)sendMail;
-(void)actionSheet;
```

When I want to build and run, I have the following error :

```
Undefined symbols:
      "_sendMail", referenced from:
      -[my1ViewController actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in my1ViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand what is going on. If I copy/paste what's inside my sendMail function inside my (void)actionSheet function, it works like a charm. So it looks like the call of the sendMail function is the problem, and I don't understand why.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C calls methods not functions and it's like this:

```
[self sendMail];
```

Comment: No worries! Feel free to give us a shiny green tick :P